# php array into JS variables with AJAX

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, post

i have a php array:

```
$Array= array ($eventRow['title'], $eventRow['start_date'], $eventRow['start_time'], $eventRow['end_date'], $eventRow['end_time'], $eventRow['description'], $eventRow['address']);
```

i am exeucing an ajax script with a html button, and i would like to get these variable's values as the following:

```
(document).ready(function() {

    //##### send add record Ajax request to outlookimport.php #########
    $(".exportOutlook").click(function() {

        /*var myData = {
            title:
            startDate:
            startTime:
            endDate:
            endTime:
            description:
            address:
            username:

        };*/
...
```

any idea how to get the values in the JS file when processing the ajax query? 
after this, a php file as called by the ajax, when i would like to get the variable as the following:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$startDate = $_POST['startDate'];
...
...
```

any idea would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, it's:

```
$.post('outlookimport.php', myData, function (returnedData) {
    //Do something
});
```

By including `myData` as the second parameter, its values will be posted to the PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode($Array)` and read the JSON response in your ajax request on success.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'outlookimport.php',
    data: myData,    
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: you mean here? :

        `jQuery.ajax({

            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "outlookimport.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"json", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //Form variables
            success:function(response){
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            }`

Comment: @user3576148 are you echoing the array as json format in your php ? see my answer